# What is the correct way to install Gnome Shell 3.6 on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: gnome

I don't want to use Ubuntu Gnome Remix because I think it is kind of "incomplete". I prefer to install Gnome Shell on Ubuntu 12.10. I've searched the net for instructions on how to do it and found two different ways:

1. Simply search for Gnome Shell on Ubuntu Software Center and install it.
2. Follow the instructions from this [WebUpd8's post](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-get-complete-gnome-3-desktop-in.html).

Now, my doubt is: what is the differecen between the two methods? Which is the correct way to do it? Does the first one lack features? If so, which ones? Is the second one better? Why? Is there a third and better method I haven't found?

By the way, I have already tried (for testing purposes) the second method (WebUpd8's) and noticed that it installed some apps I really don't want to have, such as AbiWord and Gnumeric, because they are Gnome's default applications. So, "if" the second method is the way to go, I can certainly remove those apps manually, after installation, with no worries, right?

Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

### There are three correct ways of installing gnome-shell here:

1. Install gnome-shell from Ubuntu Software Center (this is equivalent to running `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`)
2. Follow the instructions on the [Ubuntu GNOME Remix](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/ReleaseNotes/12.10#Upgrade) page. This installs gnomes-shell and the gnome default settings.
3. Follow the instructions on the webupd8 page. This installs gnome-shell, the default settings, updates the included GNOME apps to the most recent version, and installs more of the GNOME apps that default Ubuntu leaves out.

All three methods properly "install gnome-shell. They do it to varying degrees of adherence to upstream GNOME releases.

Answer (score 0):

Check the instructions available in [Ubuntu GNOME Remix](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/ReleaseNotes/12.10#Upgrade) and how to add the [stuffs not included by default](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/ReleaseNotes/12.10#What.27s_Not_Included).